# Why is my OCMock andDo expectation only called the first time

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I've been mocking out accesses to the Parse Data backend and run into trouble with OCMock.

The primary data access mechanism for accessing the backend is through a Parse
`PFQuery` object, constructed with `[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"]`.
This is naturally a good choice as a test seam.

I want to use Partial mocks in this case for reasons I will not go into in this post.

Instead of returning a real PFQuery, I can rig this class method to return a mock object like so:

```
id queryMock = OCMClassMock([PFQuery class]);
OCMStub([queryMock queryWithClassName:className]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation){
    id mockQuery = OC...;
    NSLog(@">> CREATED MOCK QUERY: %@, %p", mockQuery, &mockQuery);
    [invocation setReturnValue:&mockQuery];
});
```

... with the mock query's set up like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:className];

id mockQuery = OCMPartialMock(query);

OCMStub([mockQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:[OCMArg any]]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    typedef void (^FindObjectsBlock)(NSArray *, NSError *error);

    FindObjectsBlock callback;
    [invocation getArgument:&callback atIndex:2];

    NSArray *results = evaluateQueryResultArrayFromDataArray(query, objects);

    callback(results, nil);
});
```

But to mimic the behaviour of the SDK, I would like to be able to call this
method multiple times, and I expect distinct mock objects to be produced. This is important.

I chose to use OCMock's class method mocking capabilities. I found that if I invoke the class method twice, the mocking behaviour only applies to the first time. The second time, mocking is ineffective.

```
        NSLog(@"BEFORE first");
        PFQuery *firstQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"THINGS"];
        NSLog(@"AFTER first");

        // Configure first query...

        NSLog(@"BEFORE second");
        PFQuery *secondQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"THINGS"];
        NSLog(@"AFTER second");

        // Configure second query...

        expect(secondQuery).toNot.equal(firstQuery);            // OK

        [firstQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"THIS IS EXECUTED CORRECTLY %@", objects);   // OK; returns array as expected
        }];

        // The following query FAILS because the real underlying method is called.
        [secondQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"THIS DOESN'T EXECUTE RIGHT %@", objects);   // FAILS
        }];
```

The trace clearly shows the `.andDo()` behaviour is executed once only.

```
2014-10-21 16:23:53.186 xctest[18380:209978] BEFORE first
2014-10-21 16:23:53.188 xctest[18380:209978] >> CREATED MOCK QUERY: OCPartialMockObject(PFQuery), 0x7fff5e74d980
2014-10-21 16:23:53.188 xctest[18380:209978] AFTER first
2014-10-21 16:23:53.188 xctest[18380:209978] BEFORE second
2014-10-21 16:23:53.188 xctest[18380:209978] AFTER second
```

Why is this?

Comment: Whatever happened to the repetition primitives, like `[... times:3]`?

Comment: Haven't found the time to implement them yet.

Comment: (ignore this comment, see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Only one mock object can stub class methods for a given class. The documentation says the effect is undefined when two mock objects try to stub class methods on the same class. In the current implementation a later mock will take over stubbing from the previous mock, meaning that when you create a mock for a given class, all class method stubs created by other mocks for the same class get removed.

In your case you create a mock for `PFQuery` to stub the `queryWithClassName:` method. When that stub gets called its implementation creates a new (partial) mock for `PFQuery`. With the current implementation of OCMock, as described above, that new mock is now the only mock that can stub class methods on `PFQuery`, but it hasn't declared a stub for the `queryWithClassName:` method...